# Formula that maps the index of a numpy array to the corresponding index in the flattened vector?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensor

As in the title, what is the formula that maps the index of a numpy array to the corresponding index in the flattened vector?

As a concrete example:

```
np.random.seed(2021)
X = np.random.normal(size=(5,4,3))
x = X.flatten(order='C')
ix = (1,2,2)
```

What is the formula to calculate the index `i` such that `x[i]` returns the same value as `X[ix]`? Ideally this same formula would work for higher-order tensors as well.

Comment: `numpy.ravel_multi_index` does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that retunes partial index based on the relative position of the value in `X` buy multiplying the number of arrays and rows with the values in `ix`

```
def calculate_index(x, i):
    return x[0].size * i

np.random.seed(2021)
X = np.random.normal(size=(5, 4, 3))
x = X.flatten(order='C')
x[calculate_index(X, ix[0]) + calculate_index(X[0], ix[1]) + ix[2]]
```

`X, ix[0]` will give the relative index based on number of lists (5).

`X[0], ix[1])` will give the relative index based on number of rows in list (4).

`ix[2]` will give the relative index on the row.

```
ix = (1, 2, 2)
print(X[ix])
# -0.720158835135297
print(x[calculate_index(X, ix[0]) + calculate_index(X[0], ix[1]) + ix[2]])
# -0.720158835135297


ix = (3, 3, 0)
print(X[ix])
# 1.2242357215843627
print(x[calculate_index(X, ix[0]) + calculate_index(X[0], ix[1]) + ix[2]])
# 1.2242357215843627
```